# Does the monotonicity of $L^p$ norms holds when the norm goes to infinity?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces

It is fine to prove that the function $f: p\rightarrow||X||_p$ for non-negative and finite $p$ is monotone using Jensen's equality by defining a convex function $\phi(x) = |x|^{q/p}, 1<p<q<\infty:$

$||X||_p=(\mathbb{E}[|X|^p])^{1/p}=(\phi(\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]))^{1/q}$

$\leq(\mathbb{E}[\phi(|X|^p)]^{1/q}=(\mathbb{E}[|X|^q])^{1/q}=||X||_q$.

However, I am completely lost when I need to prove the monotonicity for $||X||_p = \infty$.

What should I deal with?

Comment: $||X||_p= \infty$ if and only if $E[|X|^p]=\infty$. The latter implies that for all q>p, $E[|X|^q]=\infty$ as the $L_p$ spaces are decreasing when the measure is finite. Is that what you meant in your question?

Comment: @Kolmo I appreciate your reply. So you meant I do not need to add words as $\mathbb{E}|[X|^p]=\infty \leq \mathbb{E}|[X|^q]$ when $p<q$ - monotonicity still holds?

Comment: Yes, monotonicity still holds

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that if $1\lt p \lt q \lt \infty$, then $\lVert X\rVert_p \leqslant \lVert X\rVert_q$. We have for a fixed $R$ thzt 
$$\lVert X\mathbf 1\left\{\left|X\right|\lt R\right\} \rVert_p\leqslant \lVert X\mathbf 1\left\{\left|X\right|\lt R\right\} \rVert_q.$$
Then we can conclude by the monotone convergence theorem (which can be used if the limit is finite or $+\infty$).